# react native flexbox issue on Android

Tags: flexbox, react-native

**Overview**
I have tried to use flex box on android for an hour now, and could not seem to get it to work. So I have taken a simple snippet from the react-native site to demonstrate my issue.

**Main Issue**

`exampleContainer: { flex: 1 }`

will not account for android screen space.

**Picture Proof**

[ios vs Android](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rPZoz.png)

**Code Snippet**

```js
export default class App extends Component {
  constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      environment: props.environment,
      message: `Environment: ${props.environment}`
    }
  }

  static defaultProps() {
    return {environment: "Unknown"}
  }

  render(){
    return (
          // Try setting `alignItems` to 'flex-start'
          // Try setting `justifyContent` to `flex-end`.
          // Try setting `flexDirection` to `row`.
          <View style={{
            flex: 1,
            alignSelf: 'stretch',
            flexDirection: 'column',
            justifyContent: 'center',
            alignItems: 'center'
          }}>
            <View style={{width: 50, height: 50, backgroundColor: 'powderblue'}} />
            <View style={{width: 50, height: 50, backgroundColor: 'skyblue'}} />
            <View style={{width: 50, height: 50, backgroundColor: 'steelblue'}} />
          </View>
        );
  }
}
```

**UPDATE**
I fixed this issue by giving root node (./index..js) a flex style.

[Solution and Picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qPd3j.png)

Answer (score 1):

To get react-native flex box working properly for both android and ios, your root view must have a flex style applied to it so that the immediate children know how much space is available.